# Zoom out not working in network topology graph using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, zooming

I have a network topology graph generated using d3.js.

Have added zoom functionality as follows

```
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([0, 0])
    .scaleExtent([1, 3])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("div#<name>").append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
    .call(zoom);
...

var containerGrp = svg.append("g");
...
function zoomed() {
    var e = d3.event,
    tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[0], width - width * e.scale)),
    ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[1], height - height * e.scale));
    zoom.translate([tx, ty]);
    containerGrp.attr("transform", ["translate(" + [tx, ty] + ")", "scale(" + e.scale + ")"].join(" "));
    }
```

on clicking the topology graph, it zooms in and stops. Zoom out is not working.
Can somebody tell if I am missing the code for zoomout? How does zoom out work with d3.js?

Comment: I am not sure why are you doing zoom.translate([tx, ty]); in the zoomed function.

Comment: Removed zoom.translate. Still the same.

Comment: Can you change your zoomed function to this



function zoomed(){
containerGrp.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");}

Comment: done.. same result. The zoom out works on mouse wheel scroll(with both functions). But not on click.

Comment: Sorry Not clear ...you said the zoom in and zoom out is working on mouse scroll. Or is it something else?

Comment: Yes.. On mouse scroll zoom in and zoom out are working. On click, zoom in is possible. Wanted to get zoom out also on click. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Ok just as you have registered zoom on svg.
You can also register click and call a function, in that function you can change the scale for zoom in and zoom out to work.
This example is close to want you want: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590